# How to emulate user pressing a key with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to emulate user pressing spacebar in a textarea. The code needs to be exactly as the user pressed the key. Any ideas? 
Using `jQuery.trigger()` doesn't work as it only triggers event handler for pressing a key, doesn't actually "send" a key to the text area.

Comment: The keydown event is sent to an element when the user first presses a key on the keyboard. Keydown http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Comment: @kunalbhat - jQuery.keydown -is an event *handler* - it handles an event, doesn't initiate it

Comment: Emulate for testing?  Or emulate for functional reasons?

Comment: @Andrey but it DOES initiate an event, just not with the outcome you want. http://jsfiddle.net/Gj7cB/

Comment: @KevinB - it initiates event, not the actual pressing a button in a text box. I need to push a space value into the text box, but so that it thinks that a user pressed the space bar.

Comment: If you're not doing this just for testing... why not just change the value of the input? ultimately that's the goal right?

Comment: You're not making any sense... the browser can't push the keyboard button for you, all it can do is trigger/listen to events. using .keydown triggers the event, it just doesn't perform the default action because the event didn't come from the user. You can trick it into receiving a specific keycode, but the character still won't be automagically sent to the input, you'll have to do that manually.

Comment: @KevinB - that's what I am trying to find out - whether it's possible. You can sure do that (emulate pushing a button) say in a Windows app, so I thought maybe it's possible in JS as well.

Comment: It is... it just takes a lot more than `.trigger`. `.trigger("input keydown keyup").val(function(val){return val + " ";})` though obviously that isn't perfect, it doesn't take into account cursor position or which element is focused, both of which can be taken care of with **more** code.

Answer (score 2):

To put in a space where the cursor is, replacing any selected text & positioning the cursor where it'd be if the space had been typed by the user (assuming the textarea has focus):

```
var myTextarea = document.getElementById( 'myTextarea' ),
    selStart = myTextarea.selectionStart,
    selEnd = myTextarea.selectionEnd,
    currentValue = myTextarea.value;

myTextarea.value = currentValue.substr( 0, selStart ) + ' ' + currentValue.substr( selEnd );
myTextarea.setSelectionRange( selStart + 1, selStart + 1 );
```

Of course if you need the 'keydown' event for spacebar to fire as well you'll have to trigger it separately, which is easy with jQuery:

```
var spaceEvt = new $.Event( 'keydown', { keyCode: 32 });
$( myTextarea ).trigger( spaceEvt );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need this only for testing purposes I would recommend writing a [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) script.